# How can I access github repository contents using graphql (v4 api)?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-api-v4

If I use github `v3` api to access the directory contents of a public repository using the following query:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/w3c/webappsec/contents/
```

what is the equivalent in graphql?

I can get for example the description of the repository by sending the following to: https://api.github.com/graphql

```
query TestQuery{
    repository(owner:"w3c" name:"webappsec"){
      description
    }
  }
```

But how can I get the contents of a repository's directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `object(expression: "branch_name:")` and list the tree entries:

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "w3c", name: "webappsec") {
    object(expression: "master:") {
      ... on Tree {
        entries {
          name
          type
          mode
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22w3c%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22webappsec%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20object(expression%3A%20%22master%3A%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Tree%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entries%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mode%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)